# How to allow static url routes to exist on a dynamic url namespace

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

So I have 2 routes in angular-ui-router, one static and one dynamic

```
$stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
      })
      .state('profile', {
        url: '/:username',
        templateUrl: 'profile.html'
      })
      ;
```

How can I make sure that one does not clash with the other?

====

EDIT:

Now I found out that 'profile' clashes with root:

```
.state('root', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'root.html'
      })
      ;
```

Navigating to '/' displays the profile.html instead of root.html. Navigating to '/windy' shows the profile.html correctly.

Comment: You put the static before the dynamic, like you've done. heh

Comment: Oh nvm, these are states. So I see no reason for them to clash since you're using ui-sref='home' etc (right?). Maybe if you have a username called 'home' these urls could be the same, is this the case?

Comment: The UI-Router will evaluate match in order states where defined. First wins. But if I could suggest: Do not rely on something like that. I'd say that your users won't so much mind, if the second url would be /profile/profileName... and you'll later won't solve weired issues with routing

Comment: This design is wrong IMO; you would also have to check that a user name cannot be "home", which is an arbitrary restriction. It seems much better to put users under their own URL, e.g. `'/profile/:username'`.

Comment: @Nikos unfortunately that is not possible. I have to show /:username. Like how facebook manages their profile page urls.

Comment: @Erik, what if users land on the page '/home' from search engine results? How does UI-router decide which template to display?

Comment: @ShawnLim I believe Radim is correct in how urls are evaluated, first declared first served.